# Create an em-dash in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, alt-code

I would like to create an [em-dash](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/emdash) aka —

I know using ALT Codes in Windows I can hold down <kbd>ALT</kbd> and type `0151`

But my issue is on my laptop (a Dell Vostros 3555) it doesn't work!

I am running Windows 7 and was attempting to create one in Gmail. If I am on my desktop I have no issue creating one in Gmail or elsewhere for that matter.

Is there something I must do to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Charmap: (*Start -> Run -> Charmap*) though this is tedious.
- Keyboard Macros: e.g. [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)

Some laptops have a way to overlay a numeric pad on the main part of the keyboard, enabled  by some key combination (Fn + ???) - but this is rare now.

Comment: That is why. Lack of numpad and my laptop doesn't have the numeric pad overlay. I will do what you recommend or find a program that will create symbols and use that to create the — when I need one. => Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have Word installed, you may press Ctrl+Atl+NumpadMinus in Word and then copy and paste em-dash from Word to the web browser.

Comment: What about when I do not have Word installed?

Comment: A Dell Vostro 3555 doesn't have a NumpadMinus key does it?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick - No it does not.